# Does Android App Bundle Automatically Load Classes From Downloaded APKs?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am trying the Android App Bundle and the dynamic feature module. The dynamic module will be built into a separate APK from the base module.

I wonder how do I use the source code and classes from the dynamic module in the base module? Will the classes be automatically loaded by the play.core library after downloading the additional APKs from the play store? Do I need to handle the class loading myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [dynamic features sample on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features).

The sample uses a `BaseSplitActivity` which overrides `onAttachBaseContext` like this:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    SplitCompat.install(this)
}
```

This makes sure that the newly downloaded split is properly installed when the activity launches.

In case of assets you'll have to create a new package context [like this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt#L151)

```
private fun displayAssets() {
    // Get the asset manager with a refreshed context, to access content of newly installed apk.
    val assetManager = createPackageContext(packageName, 0).assets
    // Now treat it like any other asset file.
    val assets = assetManager.open("assets.txt")
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For example, I have some views in the dynamic module. Is it possible to use those views in the base module? I think I can use class loader to load those views from the downloaded apks, but does the play core library help me handle such things?

Comment: You'll have to use reflection to access the views. PlayCore does consider itself with serving / deleting modules, not accessing code in the modules.